# Updating existing bean instances for child collection

Tags: java, collections, parent-child, mapstruct

I have child collection

```
public class SectorDto {
    List<RentalObjectDto> rentalObjects;
}
@Entity
public class Sector {
    List<RentalObject> rentalObjects;
}
```

and before mapping I have Sector with child collection from DB. Then I use @MappingTarget to update existing bean

```
Sector map(SectorDto sectorDto, @MappingTarget Sector sectorDb);
```

I need the same possibility for child elements. But generated code doesn't want to use this method with **@MappingTarget**

```
RentalObject map(RentalObjectDto rentalObjectDto, @MappingTarget RentalObject rentalObjectDb)
```

the same when I add method for list with **@MappingTarget** it also generates own method without **@MappingTarget** for collection members.

```
List<RentalObject> mapRentalObjects(List<RentalObjectDto> rentalObjectDtos,
                                    @MappingTarget List<RentalObject> rentalObjectsDb);
```

My intention is to update already existing in DB collection members, to add new, and to remove orphans, because child **Entity** class (the same as parent) has additional properties witch aren't in **Dto** class, and it is important not to lose them. I ended up with complicated default method witch works in my case,

```
 default List<RentalObject> mapRentalObjects(List<RentalObjectDto> rentalObjectDtos,
                                    @MappingTarget List<RentalObject> rentalObjectsDb) {

    if ( rentalObjectDtos == null ) { return null;}

    List<RentalObject> rentalObjectsDbForRemove = new ArrayList<>();

    // map existing
    for ( RentalObject rentalObjectDb : rentalObjectsDb ) {
        Optional<RentalObjectDto> rentalObjectDto = rentalObjectDtos.stream()
                .filter(ro->ro.getId()!=null)
                .filter(ro->ro.getId().equals(rentalObjectDb.getId())).findFirst();
        if (rentalObjectDto.isPresent()){
            map(rentalObjectDto.get(), rentalObjectDb);
        } else {
            rentalObjectsDbForRemove.add(rentalObjectDb);
        }
    }
    // remove orphan
    rentalObjectsDb.removeAll(rentalObjectsDbForRemove);

    // add new
    rentalObjectDtos.stream()
            .filter(roDto->roDto.getId()==null)
            .map(roDto-> mapRentalObjectDb(roDto,new RentalObject())
            .forEach((roDto)->rentalObjectsDb.add(roDto));

    return rentalObjectsDb;
}
```

Does mapstuct have an easier solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Updating collections is a tricky problem and requires a complex solution like you can see in your example.

Therefore MapStruct does not provide a way to achieve such a complex scenario.

The solution for this would be to write a custom method like you did and use that for mapping is the only way in the moment.

Comment: Do you think this could be a good thing for contribution ?

Comment: We would need to see how this looks like. Not sure how it would fit. We would need to see some draft for it.

Answer (score 0):

Two years, 4 months late for the party, but you can force MapStruct to use

```
RentalObject map(RentalObjectDto rentalObjectDto, @MappingTarget RentalObject rentalObjectDb);
```

by providing

```
RentalObject map(RentalObjectDto rentalObjectDto) {
    map(rentalObjectDto, /* here instantiate rentalObjectDb by rentalObjectDto */
}
```

Usually instantiation is done by resolving the id contained in the dto.

Comment: started a discussion regarding this: https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/discussions/3381